# Is there a way in Xcode to inquiry file statistics: total lines, total statements etc.?

Tags: xcode, ios7

I was looking for something I believe very basic - the total number of lines, not showing line numbers for every line. I would appreciate if you know how to do it, in particular in Xcode5. Thanks!

Comment: In a Terminal navigate to the folder where the code files are located then enter `wc`. First column show  number of lines per file, second is words, third column is characters.

Comment: @Olaf: good explanation of `wc`. This extends my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it by scrolling down to last line to see Number of lines by enabling this :

[image]

Or, you can use terminal command to find as :

```
wc -l AppDelegate.m
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want that Xcode editor show line numbers for every line in Xcode 5 simply hold down the **cmd** and **,** buttons together and a window will pop up.like below image[image]

just click the line numbers and what ever you want in editor....
i hope this will help you

Comment: Exactly same as mine answer. But this looks like Xcode4, OP asked for Xcode 5.